# redux-form Initializing FieldArray with Array of Objects

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-form

I've checked the examples for `FieldArray` and all searches/issues point towards passing a simple array as initializer. But I'm not sure how to make the `Field` display initial value, if the array consists of objects.

```
const renderFields = ({ fields, command }) => fields.map((name, index, fields) => {
  const { type, component } = getRenderer(command, name)
  const { fieldDescription, fieldName } = fields.get(index)
  return <Field key={`${name}.${fieldName}`} name={`${name}.${fieldName}`} type={type} component={component} label={fieldDescription} />
})

// usage

const Command = ({ command }: Props) => (
  <div className="command">
    <FieldArray name={`${command}.fields`} component={renderFields} command={command} />
  </div>
)
```

The `initialValues` would look like:

```
{
  id: 'some identifier',
  abc: { include: true, fields: [{fieldDescription, fieldName, value }, ...]
  def: { include: true, fields: [{fieldDescription, fieldName, value }, ...]  
}
```

`abc`, `def` are passed as `command` to `renderFields`.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out - the trick was to NOT use a `FieldArray`.

```
const renderMembers = ({ fieldDefs, command }) => {
  const fields = fieldDefs[command].members
  return (
    <FormSection key={i} name={`${c}`}>
      {fields.map((member, index) => {
        const name = `members.${member.name}`
        return (
            <Field
              key={index}
              name={name}
              type="text"
              component={renderField}
              label={member.label}
            />            
        )
      })}
    </FormSection>
  )
}


const Command = ({ command }: Props) => (
  <div className="command">
    {renderMembers({fieldDefs, key: c})}
  </div>
)
```

Fully working example: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/1vqqn68zx4)